# hotel room booking facility wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Can anyone suggest which plugins to be used for hotel room booking ? I need the facility like check in date,check out date,room type,number of adults and number of children. After clicking the submit button in the front I wanted to show all the room details, gallery images of that room, price of that room, and booking option. Then I wanted to send the booking details to a mail. Then booking payment should be done by credit card options.

I first used bookingo facility. It is so  complicated. So I dropped it.

Then I have used the awe booking , contact form 7 and woo commerce plugins for this but when I installed the woo commerce plugin, a message "your theme doesnot support". Can anyone tell a solution or suggest another plugin which I can use for booking rooms in a hotel?

Answer (score 2):

for "your theme doesnot support" to add in your theme functions.php file add this support to working woocommerce like

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90199/how-to-declare-woocommerce-support-in-your-theme